# why After call end its not detect incomingNumber value and On direct reject call it detects Value

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to start a dialog box after call end but application forced to closed and Even if i use toast after that in toast value of incomingNumber not detected even toast also not shown, i think when call received application stops detection but am not sure please revert me on this.

public class CallHelper extends Activity {

```
private int prev_state;
final Context context = this;
String myNum;

/**
 * Listener to detect incoming calls.
 */
private class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (incomingNumber != null && incomingNumber.length() > 0) {

            myNum = incomingNumber;

            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

                prev_state = 0;
                // Toast.makeText(ctx, "Phone recieved of : " + myNum,
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

                prev_state = 1;
                // Toast.makeText(ctx, "Phone coming from : " + myNum,
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

                if (prev_state == 0) {

                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Not recieved : " + myNum,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if (prev_state == 1) {

                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Phone was from : " + myNum,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Broadcast receiver to detect the outgoing calls.
 */
public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public OutgoingReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Outgoing: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }

}

private Context ctx;
private TelephonyManager tm;
private CallStateListener callStateListener;
private OutgoingReceiver outgoingReceiver;

public CallHelper(Context ctx) {

    this.ctx = ctx;

    callStateListener = new CallStateListener();
    outgoingReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
}

/**
 * Start calls detection.
 */
public void start() {
    tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);
    ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
}

/**
 * Stop calls detection.
 */
public void stop() {
    tm.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    ctx.unregisterReceiver(outgoingReceiver);
}
```

}

Comment: Check this : http://karanbalkar.com/2014/02/detect-incoming-call-and-call-hangup-event-in-android/

Comment: @RIT Thank you sir, but i want to toast after call_end and it shows received that number on which talked last. e.g after telephonic conversation, instead of call summary it shows that mobile number.

Comment: You go through once again, you will get your answer. It is already there. Also when you get correct answer/comment mark/upvote it. So other can follow that answer. This is stackoverflow.

Comment: You should upvote that answer/comment. This is how stackoverflow works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when pohne call ends, it only detects that a phone call is ended. It does not offers the number. If you want number, then you have to save number at TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING. Then use this phone number when phone call ends.

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @wasim Thank you for your affordabe answer, I tried but it's not detect on after CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK > CALL_STATE_IDLE no toast happen, If you want than i can show my full code to you to understand give me your email_id

Comment: I already mentioned that you have to save the number in ON_STATE_RINGING..CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK and CALL_STATE_IDLE do not offer the number